# Adding partials to 'grunt build' when building an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

How can I add a line/s to my Grunt file to make sure it finds the partial views?

My grunt.js file is the vanilla one provided when you scaffold an AngularJS app with Yeoman, no plugins or JQuery, just Angular.

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you have tried and which plugins you're using?

Comment: Updated question for you. Thanks.

Comment: Are you putting the partials in a different folder than the stock `/views`?

Comment: Yeah, views/partials... It just does it for SCSS partials. Really confused!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@JohnRobertPett if you could provide the source code of your Gruntfile I could point out exactly where to do it on your file.

As I am also using Yeoman and I've played around with it a lot, I am quite sure you should have the following piece of code on your Gruntfile.js:

```
htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {

    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/**/*.html', 'partials/**/*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},
```

You can see above that on the `htmlmin` task I added the two folders of my views and partials (template for directives) to be used by Grunt.

If you are still stuck, please share your Gruntfile.js and I can help you further.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks. Can I apply this technique to all other file types (JS, CSS, HTML)?

Comment: it depends... If you would like the files to be part of the minification process, then YES... you should include them in the `htmlmin` task. But sometimes you don't want files to be minified, for example, some .txt files or .ico so you can include them in the COPY task instead. Pleasure to help :)

Comment: I have managed to get everything running now, apart from one thing: The images get renamed when I build the app, but they don't get renamed in the HTML or CSS. Do you know why?

Comment: Good progress! :)
I guess the issue you are having now is related to the `rev:` task on your Gruntfile.js. If you remove the `'rev'` task (or comment it out) from the task list it should keep the same file names (without the hash in the beginning) and you should't have this problem anymore.

Comment: Even though the question was poorly asked, you answered my question (which appears to be the OP's), which was: if I put my partial HTML (aka templates) in a different place than Yeoman expects (I group them with my scripts so that both the JS and the HTML are together in the same directory), adding 'scripts/**/*.html' worked perfectly.